# CRM 2013 Opportunity and Opportunity Product navigation Bug

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am having trouble with the navigation between an Opportunity and its' related Products i.e. Opportunity Product.

To replicate my issue, simply open any Opportunity Product from the grid on the Opportunity Form.  The Opportunity Product opens as expected.  However, it is not possible to get back to the related Opportunity to which the Opportunity Product belongs to.

When following the same steps on a Quote (double click Quote Product on the sub grid) the Quote Product opens up in a new window and there is no need to navigate back to the related Quote.

Does anyone know of a workaround?  Hitting back in the Browser is not a proper solution for me.  I don't know if this is maybe a bug on the new software?

Comment: If I'm right the same behavior happens with price list and price list items

Answer (score 0):

When you Open or Create an Opportunity Product, just click the "Save and Close" button.  (I'm assuming that it opens within the same window).

Probably not a bug but an "intentional feature :P

Comment: There is no "Save and Close" feature on 2013.  It is definitely a bug.  Open a Quote Product and Compare the functionality.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like "Save and Close" only appears when Auto-Save is turned off.  So yes, it's a bug.